# How to Create an auto-increment value on MySQL using a text field?

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to generate an auto increment value but MySQL does not implement it.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Thanks you, I am happy to discover with you

Comment: I think that it would be far more intelligent to keep the same information in 3 columns: id int auto-increment, user_name VARCHAR(10), date_created DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP that way you can format as you like in a query, do date calculations etc. There is no need of a procedure, and the storage space is optimised.

Comment: @Kendle I understand you, but the problem is that you have to avoid rewriting the same code several times each time you want to do an insertion, so it is better to put it in a procedure that will allow the reuse of the code for another table

Comment: I understand that you have not choice if you have to operate a legacy system. I do feel that you are doing a lot of useless calculations and wasteing storage space with such a long id. Imagine that every time you do a join based on id the database engine has to do a varchar comparison that takes as much computing power for each character as the whole integer comparison.

Comment: Use common numeric autoincrement. Create generated column with the expression which deterministically generates needed text value using numeric autoincrement as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many things to solve the problem. Let me show you one of them by using MySQL procedures.

Steps are as follows:

1°) create a procedure that generates an identifier for a table (generate_id)

2°) create a procedure that inserts the data into the table (insert_users) by using the first procedure (generate_id) to get a formatted ID, then it will return the inserted ID as a SELECT query.

3°) Now, call the inserting procedure (insert_users)

For more information, chat with [Michel Magloire Ekanga](https://facebook.com/adam.saozer) who is the main creator of this craftiness.

LET'S USE AN EXAMPLE FOR EACH STEP

### STEP 1

generate_id procedure that should take as parameters: table_name, the primary_key, a joiner or a prefix for ID, the length for ID, and the output

Our result should be as below: USER20210909000002 (joiner=USER, year=2021, mounth=09, day=09, increment=000002)

```
# ---------------------   DEFINITION ------------------------------
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS generate_id;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE generate_id(IN _db_table VARCHAR(255), IN _pkey VARCHAR(255),IN _joiner VARCHAR(255),_length INT, OUT _new_id VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    SET @max_id = NULL;
    SET @sql = CONCAT('select max(`', _pkey, '`)  into @max_id from `', _db_table, '`');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    #------- Length for identifier -------
    SET @length = 10;
    SET @joiner_len = CHAR_LENGTH(_joiner);
    IF _length > 0 AND (_length - CHAR_LENGTH(_joiner)) >= 10 THEN
    SET @length = _length;
    END IF;
    #----------------------------
    #--- the date variables ---
    SET @today = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y%m%d');
    SET @r_str = LPAD(1,(@length - (8 + @joiner_len)), '0');
    #
    #---- FORMATING ID ------------------------
    #
    IF @max_id IS NULL THEN 
    # the table is empty
    SET _new_id = CONCAT(_joiner,@today,@r_str);
    ELSE 
    # the table is not empty
    # 1°) reading parts from previous ID 
    SET @strlen = CHAR_LENGTH(@max_id);
    SET @old_r_str = SUBSTR(@max_id, (@joiner_len + 4 + 2 + 2 + 1), @strlen);
    SET @old_idx = CONVERT(@old_r_str, SIGNED INTEGER);
    # 2°) checking if dates are the same
    SET @old_date = SUBSTR(@max_id, (@joiner_len + 1), 8);
    -- dates are not the same, we just take the 8 characters for date from the field
    SET @new_idx = 1;
    SET @new_r_str = LPAD(@new_idx,(@length - (8 + @joiner_len)), '0');
    SET @new_max = CONCAT(_joiner,@today,@new_r_str);
    IF @today = @old_date THEN
        SET @new_idx = @old_idx + 1;
        SET @new_r_str = LPAD(@new_idx,(@length - (8 + @joiner_len)), '0');
        SET @new_max = CONCAT(_joiner,@old_date,@new_r_str);
    END IF;
    SET _new_id =  @new_max;
    END IF;
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

### STEP 2

Procedure that uses the generated ID for insertion, we don't need to provide an ID, it will generate the ID automaticaly

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insert_users;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE insert_users(
    login_user VARCHAR(255),
    pass_user VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
    CALL generate_id('users', 'row_id', 'USR', 22, @new_id);
    SET @last_inserted_id = @new_id;
    SET @sql = CONCAT("INSERT INTO users(row_id, login_user, pass_user) VALUES ('", 
        @last_inserted_id, "','",
        login_user, "','",
        pass_user, "')"
    );
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    # ---- export the new ID before exiting the function
    SELECT @last_inserted_id AS lastInsertId;

END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

### STEP 3

How to use with PHP, for example

```
<?php

function insert(){
    $db = $pdo; // I am using PDO as driver, renewed as Class
    $lastInsert = null;
    //---------------
    $sql = "CALL insert_users(?,?)";
    //---------------
    
    $req = $db->prepare($sql);
    $req->execute($login_user,$pass_user);
    if($req->rowCount() > 0){
        $lastInsert = $req->fetch()->lastInsertId;
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

?>
```